# How to assign Network information to DiagrammeR grViz using vector

Tags: r, igraph, graphviz, digraphs, diagrammer

I have an adjacency matrix and want to use `DiagrammeR Graphviz` language to create a digraph of it.

Bellow is my adjacency matrix `MM`

```
MM<-matrix(c(1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1), 5, byrow=T)
colnames(MM)<-c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
row.names(MM)=colnames(MM)
MM
  A B C D E
A 1 1 0 0 0
B 1 1 1 1 0
C 0 1 1 1 0
D 0 1 0 1 1
E 0 0 0 1 1
```

Taking the information on DiagrammeR site [diagrammeR Docs](http://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/graphviz_and_mermaid.html) and I can create the digraph using the following code:

```
grViz("
digraph boxes_and_circles {

      # a 'graph' statement
      graph [overlap = true, fontsize = 10]

      node [shape = circle,
      fixedsize = true,
      width = 0.9] // sets as circles
        A; B; C; D; E



      # several 'edge' statements
      A->A A->B B->A B->B B->C B->D C->B C->C C->D D->B D->D D->E E->D E->E
    }")
```

This works fine to create the digraph from `MM`, but as you can see, to describe all nodes, and all nodes interactions for a bigger code will become too cumbersome, and the idea is to have it simplified.

So, my idea was to use a vector to indicate both the nodes and the nodes interaction, but this is where I fail. I tried using `igraph` to convert the adjacency matrix `MM` to graph format and from there extract the nodes interaction and try to assign that information to the previous code. Following is the code I used for this:

```
graphMM <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(MM, mode = c("directed"),
        weighted = NULL, diag = TRUE, add.colnames = NULL, add.rownames = NA)
edgesMp<-as_edgelist(graphMM)
n_int<-c(0)
for(i in 1:nrow(edgesMM)){
    n_int[i]<-paste(edgesMM[i,1], edgesMM[i,2], sep = "->")}
n_int
 [1] "A->A" "A->B" "B->A" "B->B" "B->C" "B->D" "C->B" "C->C" "C->D" "D->B"
[11] "D->D" "D->E" "E->D" "E->E"
```

I tried to assign the `n_int` vector to the code of `grViz` as:
    # several 'edge' statements
     n_int

But this only prints the word `n_int` plus the indicated nodes, each inside a circle without actually using the `n_int` information to draw the connections between the nodes.

I am aware that on `DiagrammeR` [site](http://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/graphviz_and_mermaid.html) there is shown another form to create digraphs ([graph_creation](http://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/graph_creation.html)), which allows indicating the information using vectors, but that version does not allow for subgraph construction for node orientation (e.g. graph levels corresponding to trophic levels in ecology) which I will need.

So my question is, does anyone knows how to assign nodes names and their connections to the grViz code using a vectors?

Comment: how about generating the code with `Rgraphviz`?

Comment: @user20650 the `Rgraphviz` was removed from the CRAN repository.

Comment: its at bioconductor : https://www.bioconductor.org/

Comment: I can't remember the succinct way to do this, but may give you a direction... `g <- graphAM(MM,  edgemode='directed' ) ; agwrite(agopen(g, "foo", layout=FALSE) , temp<- tempfile())` . So the `dot` code is now saved in `temp`: `cat(readLines(temp), sep="\n")`. You can probably build this in to your `grViz` workflow.